# Повторение элемента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Почему, выводит цифры от 1 до 10, а не повторяет, то, что записано в свойстве `n`? Как сделать?

```
<div id="in">
        <span v-for="n in 10">{{ n }} </span>
    </div>

    <script>
        var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#in',
          data: {
            n: {
              firstName: 'Иван',
            }
          }
        })


    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используй index для дублирования, key также является обязательным во vue2.2.0+

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="index in 10" :key="index">
    {{ n }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Подробнее тут [Документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Comment: Ответ правильный, но @DivMan также спрашивал, почему так происходит